# Call failed UI being displayed after requesting Callkit transaction with CXEndCallAction

Tags: objective-c, callkit

I am facing issue in which call failed UI of callkit being displayed after requesting Callkit transaction with CXEndCallAction. This is happening on second call. First call ends successfully without any error , but when I do the call second time, this issue happens. I am also displaying error if any from request transaction. I am not getting any error from that. What can be the cause for call failure ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you is to investigate wether `CXCallController` returns error when you request `CXEndCallAction` to him for the first call. There is a change that the first call wasn't ended successfully, and that you get Call Failed screen for that call.

Also, check if you properly call `action.fulfill()` when you finish ending the call action. Note that you should fulfill the action in the scope of `CXProvider` delegate function.

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {

    // perform the hangup

    // finally, mark the end call action as fulfilled
    action.fulfill()
}
```